# How to use logdna CLI with IBM Cloud hosted LogDNA

Tags: ibm-cloud, logdna

I am trying to get the logdna cli working with the IBM Cloud hosted LogDNA offering. I would like to search and tail logs from my machine without using the LogDNA UI.

The logdna CLI install is trivial to install but the instructions assume you are using the main logDNA hosted by logdna.com. Anyone have any instructions on how to get it working with IBM Cloud's instances?

https://docs.logdna.com/docs/logdna-cli

https://github.com/logdna/logdna-cli

The .logdna.conf file looks like this but I assume I need to put the public endpoints for my us-east logDNA instances. I am not sure how this would be integrated with the IAM IBM Cloud uses.

Too IBM Cloud folks, The loganalysis-logdna tag does not exist and I don't have the stackoverflow reputation to create it. :(

```
VERSION_CHECK_URL = https://repo.logdna.com/mac/version
UPDATE_CHECK_URL = https://repo.logdna.com/mac/logdna.gz
UPDATE_CHECK_INTERVAL = 86400000
SSO_URL = https://logdna.com/sso/
SSO_LONG_PATH = /ext/cli-sso/
SSO_POLL_INTERVAL = 5000
DEFAULT_CONF_FILE = /Users/blah/.logdna.conf
LOGDNA_APIHOST = api.logdna.com
LOGDNA_TAILHOST = tail.logdna.com
LOGDNA_APPHOST =
LOGDNA_APISSL = true
SUPPORTS_COLORS = true
updatecheck = 1587180105124
email = user@example.com
account = XXXX
key = XXXX
token = XXXX
servicekey = XXXXXX
```

Answer (score 0):

The LogDNA CLI is not supported via SSO on IBM Cloud.